# lambda expression for finding differences

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to compare 2 folder structures and find the highest folder that isn't in the other tree.

but this will probably be more clear when given an example:
say we have these 2 folders:

```
Fo1: sub 0 (fo: 3)
 > Fo: sub 0 sub 0 (fo: 2)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 0 sub 0 (fi: 3)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 0 sub 1 (fi: 3)
 > Fo: sub 0 sub 1 (fo: 1)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 0 sub 0 (fi: 1)
 > Fo: sub 0 sub 2 (fo: 2)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 1 sub 0 (fi: 2)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 1 sub 1 (fi: 1)

Fo2: sub 0 (fo: 3)
 > Fo: sub 0 sub 0 (fo: 1)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 0 sub 0 (fi: 3)
 > Fo: sub 0 sub 1 (fo: 3)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 1 sub 0 (fi: 1)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 1 sub 1
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 1 sub 2 (fi: 4)
 > Fo: sub 0 sub 2 (fo: 2)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 2 sub 0 (fi: 1)
 >  > Fo: sub 0 sub 2 sub 1
```

So the result would be:

```
 Fo: sub 0 sub 1 sub 1
 Fo: sub 0 sub 1 sub 2
 Fo: sub 0 sub 2
```

So for example the `sub 0 sub 2 sub 0` and `sub 0 sub 2 sub 1` weren't added because the root was already added. and there was nothing added from the `sub 0 sub 0` tree because all was already there

I tried these 2 methods:

```
private static bool compareFolders(Folder folder1, Folder folder2, List<Folder> newFolders, int index = 0) {
    // if has a folder that is same or is in root
    if (folder1.title == folder2.title) {
        Console.WriteLine("Same: " + folder1.title);

        // check for childs
        index++;
        if (folder1.childs != null) {
            foreach (Folder sub in folder1.childs) {
                if (folder2.childs != null) {
                    foreach (Folder sub2 in folder2.childs) {
                        compareFolders(sub, sub2, newFolders, index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // moment there false, check if root doesn't 
    if (folder2.childs != null && folder2.childs.Count > 0)
        // folder 2 has folder that folder 1 doesn't have
        newFolders.AddRange(folder2.childs);
    return false;
}
```

This was olmost working, but I saw that every folder was compared to more folders then it should.

So I tried switching to lambda, but couldn't figure out on how to do this. This is what I got:

```
private static void compareFolders2(Folder folder1, Folder folder2, List<Folder> newFolders, int index = 0) {
    if (folder2.childs != null && folder2.childs.Count > 0) {
        if (folder1.childs != null && folder1.childs.Count > 0) {
            var similarFolders = folder1.childs.FindAll(f => folder2.childs.Select(f2 => f2.title).ToList().Contains(f.title));
            if (similarFolders.Count > 0) {
                foreach (Folder folder in similarFolders) {
                    compareFolders2(folder, folder2.childs.Find(f => f.title == folder.title), newFolders);
                }
            } else {
                newFolders.AddRange(folder2.childs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you wanna try out some stuff I made a simple C# console app that has some generation methods for testing folder structures, and printing like the examples
https://gist.github.com/cskiwi/d2e5002af98da6982971

note: not always does the second folder has folders that needs to be added, increase `sublevels` / `maxfolders` on **otherFolder** to make this more likely to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think i fixed it by doing:

```
    private static void compareFolders(Folder folder1, Folder folder2, List<Folder> newFolders) {
        if (folder2.childs != null) {
            if (folder1.childs != null) {
                // check for folder 2 childs not in folder 1
                newFolders.AddRange(folder2.childs.FindAll(f => !folder1.childs.Select(f2 => f2.title).ToList().Contains(f.title)));
                // for similar folders go one deeper
                folder1.childs.FindAll(f => folder2.childs.Select(f2 => f2.title).ToList().Contains(f.title)).ForEach(f1 => compareFolders3(f1, folder2.childs.Find(f2 => f2.title == f1.title), newFolders));
            } else {
                // folder 1 doesn't have childs so add all of folder2
                newFolders.AddRange(folder2.childs);
            }
        }
    }
```

Still checking it out but look likes it's working